# Commerce element query on custom field in console command

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, datetime, custom-field, elementquery

I'm on Craft 3.4.30 (latest 3.4) and Commerce 2.2.25 (latest 2.2):

My product type "ticket" has a custom date field with handle `productStartDate`.

E.g. the following query in TWIG works:

```
{% set products = craft.products().type('ticket').productStartDate('>= 2021-01-01 00:00:00').all() %}
```

I get nice results including my custom field `productStartDate`

I am trying the same in a console command with PHP:

```
use craft\commerce\elements\Product;
$product = Product::find()
                ->type('ticket')
                ->productStartDate('>= 2021-01-01 00:00:00')
                ->all();
```

Gives me this Exception:

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown method: craft\behaviors\CustomFieldBehavior::productStartDate()'

in /myproject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php:222

Stack trace:
#0 /myproject/storage/runtime/compiled_classes/CustomFieldBehavior.php(542): yii\base\BaseObject->__call('productStartDat...', Array)
#1 [internal function]: craft\behaviors\CustomFieldBehavior->__call('productStartDat...', Array)
#2 /myproject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(297): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /myproject/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(548): yii\base\Component->__call('productStartDat...', Array)
#4 /myproject/modules/console/controllers/WarmProductGroupsController.php(61): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->__call('productStartDat...', Array)
#5 [internal function]: modules\console\controllers\WarmProductGroupsController->actionIndex(false)
#6 /myproject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /myproject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#8 /myproject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(164): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#9 /myproject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#10 /myproject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('theme/warm-prod...', Array)
#11 /myproject/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(87): yii\console\Application->runAction('theme/warm-prod...', Array)
#12 /myproject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): craft\console\Application->runAction('theme/warm-prod...', Array)
#13 /myproject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\console\Request))
#14 /myproject/craft(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

Any hints why?

Answer (score 1):

Found it: the reason for the Exception is, that the dynamic method `productStartDate` (coming from the CustomFieldBehavior) needs an Array as parameter.

I have no clue why I get this misleading Exception though...

So finally, this works:

```
use craft\commerce\elements\Product;
$product = Product::find()
                ->type('ticket')
                ->productStartDate(['>="2021-01-01 00:00:00"'])
                ->all();
```